# Django: Combine DetailView with form

Tags: django

I am currently handling the following situation. I have a DetailView, that based on the URL slug get's data from the database.

What I am currently struggling with is how to add a ModelForm to this DetailView. The form will show different ticket types, and then the user can select the quantity he wants, before clicking on continuing to get on the checkout page (ticket booking platform). The selection will be saved in the database under the ReservedItems model.

Or would it be a better way to have a CreateView and load the DetailView data into that? I am a bit confused what approach is best, and how to do it. Could you guys help me?

Here a picture how it should look like (currently not functional):
[image]

Current views.py

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'event'

    def get_object(self):
        organiser = self.kwargs.get('organiser')
        event = self.kwargs.get('event')
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=organiser)
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)
```

Template:

```
<h1>{{ event.name }}</h1>

<small class="text-muted">
    <em>Presented by <a href="{{ event.organiser.get_absolute_url }}">{{ event.organiser.name }}</a></em>
</small>

<div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="card-body">
        Short description: {{ event.short_description }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <form action="{% url 'checkout:reserve_ticket' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
    </form>  
</div>
```

models.py

```
class ReservedItem(models.Model):
    order_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True
    )
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(
        Ticket,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='reserved_tickets'
    )
    ticket_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DetailView shouldn't restrict what sort of behaviour your view is able to perform. You can add a form to a DetailView by overriding `get_context_data` like so:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(EventDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = MyFormClass
    return context
```

After this, you can override the `post` method to handle form submission logic.

Whether you use a CreateView or DetailView is up to you. You may find that CreateView is more convenient for the functionality you're aiming for.

Comment: One more questin zubhav. If I choose the other approach and use CreateView, is it then SingleObjectMixin I need?

Comment: SingleObjectMixin is an ancestor of CreateView, so you should use CreateView. It already inherits behaviour from its parent. See this website for good Generic Class View docs https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/